Как установить правильно sqlsrv для php?
В общем я пытался установить sqlsrv, с помощью вот этой документации: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#getting-started, но у меня после вызова phpinfo нет sqlsrv.
Что находиться в php(Тип файла INI-DEVELOPMENT):
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"  
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll

Моя версия php: PHP Version 8.2.20
Мне это нужно для того, чтобы подключиться ко внешней БД, со своего локального ПК (у меня нет сервера). Но у меня появилась ошибка: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\Users\ivakov.av\Desktop\Php_Projects\sigur.php:15
И мне надо установить корректно sqlsrv, помогите, пожалуйста!
// Подключаемся к MS SQL
$serverName = ""; // Имя сервера MS SQL
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database" => "", // Имя базы данных
    "UID" => "", // Имя пользователя
    "PWD" => "" // Пароль
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}


Не был подключен файл php.ini, вопрос снят
